# Schedule a DAG in airflow to run for every 5 minutes , starting from today i.e., 2019-12-18

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to run a DAG for every 5 minutes starting from today(2019-12-18). I defined my start date as `start_date:dt.datetime(2019, 12, 18, 10, 00, 00)` and schedule interval as `schedule_interval= '*/5 * * * *'` . When I start the `airflow scheduler` I don't see any of my tasks running.

But when I modify the `start_date` as `start_date:dt.datetime(2019, 12, 17, 10, 00, 00)` i.e., Yesterdays date, the DAG runs continuously like for every 10 seconds but not 5 minutes.

I think the solution to this problem is to set the `start_date` correctly, but I could not find the perfect solution for this. Please help me!

This is my code.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
import datetime as dt
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

def print_world():
   print('world')


default_args = {
    'owner': 'bhanuprakash',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2019, 12, 18, 10, 00, 00),
    'email': ['bhanuprakash.uchula@techwave.net'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=5)
}

with DAG('dag_today',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval= '*/5 * * * *'
    ) as dag:


    print_hello = BashOperator(task_id='print_hello',
        bash_command='gnome-terminal')


    sleep = BashOperator(task_id='sleep',
        bash_command='sleep 5')


    print_world = PythonOperator(task_id='print_world',
        python_callable=print_world)

print_hello >> sleep >> print_world
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The datetime object you are passing to Airflow isn't timezone aware. Airflow uses UTC internally. The naive datetime object you are passing to Airflow may not be aligned with the scheduler's notion of time and this could be why the DAG isn't being scheduled to run midnight "today" (2019-12-18).

Instead of passing a naive datetime object like this:

```
'start_date': dt.datetime(2019, 12, 18, 10, 00, 00)
```

Try using pendulum to make your DAG timezone aware:

```
import pendulum

...
'start_date': pendulum.datetime(year=2019, month=12, day=10).astimezone('YOUR TIMEZONE'), # See list of tz database time zones here -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
```

The docs (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/timezone.html) are quite useful got getting tips on how to handle datetimes in Airflow.

As for your other question on run frequency ... DAG runs are designed to do "Catchup" on all the intervals between your start and end date by default. To disable this behavior you will need to add catchup=False when instantiating your DAG.

From the [Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html)

> **Backfill and Catchup**
>
> An Airflow DAG with a start_date, possibly an end_date, and a
>   schedule_interval defines a series of intervals which the scheduler
>   turn into individual Dag Runs and execute. A key capability of Airflow
>   is that these DAG Runs are atomic, idempotent items, and the
>   scheduler, by default, will examine the lifetime of the DAG (from
>   start to end/now, one interval at a time) and kick off a DAG Run for
>   any interval that has not been run (or has been cleared). This concept
>   is called Catchup.
>
> If your DAG is written to handle its own catchup (IE not limited to
>   the interval, but instead to “Now” for instance.), then you will want
>   to turn catchup off (Either on the DAG itself with dag.catchup =
>   False) or by default at the configuration file level with
>   catchup_by_default = False. What this will do, is to instruct the
>   scheduler to only create a DAG Run for the most current instance of
>   the DAG interval series.

I'd suggest going over the two pages I linked to get a better intuition of the basic Airflow concepts.